# jQ detecting descendants with specific CSS values

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to fish out a descendant of an object which matches both criteria:
CSS visibility: visible and CSS assigned class: foo

At any time there will only be one such object present

```
var visibleBox = $('#parentEle').find().css( ??? );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
 var visibleBox = $('#parentEle .foo').filter(function() {
   return ($(this).css('visibility') == 'visible');
});

var hiddenBox = $('#parentEle .foo').filter(function() {
       return ($(this).css('visibility') == 'hidden');
    });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TDqec/1/)

Comment: @user3024007 Please read the document before using the other solution provided with :visible selector. .Filter() will be most apt for your current situation.